# What is this notification icon with a square and 2 hills? It won't go away

Tags: notification-icons

I have an icon on the top bar of my phone that looks like a square with 2 hills. It won't go away when I clear it.

It looks like the first icon on the top in this image:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the screenshot icon, if you expand you notification drawer do you see anything related to having taken a screenshot?

Comment: No not in my gallery either. It's just there and wont clear lol

Comment: Yes, is the screenshot icon

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, this is the screenshot icon.

If you pull down the notification bar, you should see a notification that says "Screenshot is being saved" (it's not "Screenshot was saved" because you can't swipe it away and it's not "Couldn't have screenshot" because it doesn't have an `!` in it).

It's possible you accidentally hit the key combination to take a screenshot (like <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>) and that made the notification.

Answer (score -2):

Hold the icon for a couple of seconds and enter the application manager.. Find out which icon it is.. And force stop it .

Answer (score -2):

Although I can't see the image, it sounds like the NFC icon.  This was added as default on in lollipop but you can turn it off via settings.